# Update Budget Google Ads API

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I am trying to update the AmoutMicros of Budget but I don't receive error, just not update the budget:

```
        CampaignBudget budget = new CampaignBudget()
        {
            ResourceName = ResourceNames.CampaignBudget(customerId, budgetId),
            AmountMicros = (price + amount) * 100000,
            Id = budgetId
        };

        CampaignBudgetOperation budgetOperation = new CampaignBudgetOperation()
        {
            Create = budget,
            UpdateMask = FieldMasks.AllSetFieldsOf(budget),
        };

        try
        {
            MutateCampaignBudgetsResponse responseBudget = 
            budgetService.MutateCampaignBudgets(
            customerId.ToString(), new CampaignBudgetOperation[] { budgetOperation 
          });

            foreach(MutateCampaignBudgetResult result in responseBudget.Results)
            {
                updateResponse.CampignId = campaignId;
                updateResponse.Updated = true;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            return updateResponse;
        }
        catch (GoogleAdsException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure:");
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {e.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Failure: {e.Failure}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Request ID: {e.RequestId}");

            return updateResponse;
            throw;
        }
```

This code don't show me a exception, apparently it was update, but, when I go at Google Ads Dashboard, the amout still the same.

I read the documentation but I didn't find an update of a budget.

Answer (score 2):

My working code is PHP but you can refer this.

```
   private static function updateCampaignBudget(GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient, int $customerId,int $campaign_budget,string $budget_resource_name){
    // Creates a campaign budget.
    $budget = new CampaignBudget([
        'resource_name' => $budget_resource_name,
        //'delivery_method' => BudgetDeliveryMethod::STANDARD,
        'amount_micros' => $campaign_budget
        //'explicitly_shared' => false
    ]);

    // Creates a campaign budget operation.
    $campaignBudgetOperation = new CampaignBudgetOperation();
    $campaignBudgetOperation->setUpdate($budget);
    $campaignBudgetOperation->setUpdateMask(FieldMasks::allSetFieldsOf($budget));
    // Issues a mutate request.
    $campaignBudgetServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getCampaignBudgetServiceClient();
    $response = $campaignBudgetServiceClient->mutateCampaignBudgets(
        $customerId,
        [$campaignBudgetOperation]
    );

    /** @var CampaignBudget $addedBudget */
    $updatedBudget = $response->getResults()[0];
    //printf("Added budget named '%s'%s", $addedBudget->getResourceName(), PHP_EOL);

    return $updatedBudget->getResourceName();
}
```

you can use ResourceNames::forCampaignBudget(customerId, budgetId) instead of $budget_resource_name